Prometheus increase() and delta() functions returning results that are exactly x2 higher than expected
I have a Prometheus metric to count the number of successfully processed messages in a given queue:

counter_success{queueName="myTestQueue"}

Here is the output graph for this query:



My problem is that when I try to use the increase() and delta() functions in Prom, I get results that are x2 higher than what I see on the above graph.
These are the queries I am using:

increase(counter_success{queueName="myTestQueue"}[10m])


delta(counter_success{queueName="myTestQueue"}[10m])

Here are the output graphs for these queries:

Increase:



Delta:


Could someone please explain why this is?
I thought it might be due to having two result series in my metrics, but even if I zoom in to a section of the graph that has only one series, the increase() and delta() functions are still off by a factor of x2.
Am I misunderstanding the math here?

Consistency of the error, especially between delta and increase (which AFAIK work completely differently internally) implies some systemic error, most likely on the Prometheus side. Consider opening issue in their repo.

Thanks @markalex. I would be surprised if this was a Prom-level issue, since it's fairly basic functionality so I'm still leaning toward it being a user understanding miss. But you're right, if I don't find any other explanations, I'll open an issue for it. Thx!
